# Stack Implementation for Nodes containing Objects

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I have a `LinkedList` of `Nodes` that contain Integer Objects.

```
LinkedList listOfInts = new LinkedList();
```

And I add the `Objects`;

```
list.add(new Integer(8));
list.add(new Integer(5));
list.add(new Integer(3));
list.add(new Integer(4));
```

with the following `Node` class:

```
class Node {

 private Object data;
 private Node next;

 public Node(Object data) 
 {
   this.data = data;
   this.next = next;
 }

 public Object getData() 
 {
   return data;
 }

 public Node getNext() 
 {
   return next;
 }

 public void setNext(Node next) 
 {
   this.next = next;
 }
}
```

If I do something as such;

```
Node p = listOfInts.pop()
```

And then print the data,

```
System.out.println(p.getData());
```

I get the right answer: 8.

But if I want to push this number onto a new `LinkedList`;

```
LinkedList newStack = new LinkedList();
newStack.push(p);
```

It pushes the entire listOfInts, not just the first data point, 8.

```
 [8,5,3,4];
```

My question is why this happens? Since this is such a basic problem, I assume it has to do with my `push()` and `pop()` methods, but since I wrote them similar to ones I've seen in textbooks, I don't know what's wrong with them. Could anyone help me understand?

```
public Node pop()
{
  Node item = peek(); //save item to return

  if(!isEmpty())
  {
    first = first.getNext(); //delete first node
  }
  size--;
  return item; //return first saved item
}

public void push(Node item)
{
  Node next = item.getNext();
  next = first;
  first = item;
  size++;

}

public Node peek()
{
  if (isEmpty())
  {
    System.out.println("Error: No element");
  }
  return first;
}
```

EDIT: Did as suggested with returning Objects instead of `Nodes`, and code is more or less the same except for `push()` method. So, when I try to add another object to the same `LinkedList`, it replaces the old one instead of adding to the list.

```
 //push node on top of the stack
 public void push(Object item)
 {

   Node newNode = new Node(item);
   Node next = newNode.getNext();
   next = first;
   first = newNode;

   size++;
  }//push
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is returning the `Node` object when `pop` is called, but the `Node` still has a reference to the "next" position within the original stack.

When you create a new stack, and you push the popped item, the original `Node` object is along for the ride, with its original `next` reference.

```
listOfInts -----> { 5 } -> { 3 } -> { 4 }
                    ^
newStack  -> { 8 } -+
```

That is why the whole list appears on the new stack.

The solution is not to expose the `Node` object at all.  Instead of accepting a `Node` in `push`, accept the data item, and create your own `Node`.  Instead of returning a `Node` in `pop` and `peek`, extract the data item from the `Node` and return it.  This way you don't inadvertently risk leaking the reference to the next `Node` in the desired node.

Comment: Thank-you for your suggestion! That makes a lot more sense. If I could ask another question though, I edited my push() method, but as I stated above, it seems to be over-writing the previous Objects when I add new Objects to the same `LinkedList` instead of forming a list. Any suggestions on how to fix this?